# Meaning of the cost of constructing a matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, newton-raphson, error-propagation, rounding-error

In a text I saw written, $``$The dominant costs in this method are the construction of the Jacobian matrix $\textbf{f}_\textbf{x}(\textbf{x}_n)$ (typically $\mathcal{O}(m^2)$) and solution of the linear system (typically $\mathcal{O}(m^3)$). What do the $``$orders of cost" mean? The text is not so clear about them. The method is the Newton-Raphson method. The linear system talked about here is $\textbf{f}_\textbf{x}(\textbf{x}_n)\Delta \textbf{x}_\textbf{n}=\textbf{f}(\textbf{x}_n)$ where $\Delta\textbf{x}_\textbf{n}=\textbf{x}_n-\textbf{x}_{n+1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Order of cost* means the number of elementary operations. Typically the number of additions and multiplications.

For example $\mathcal O(m³)$ means that there is a constant $M >0$ such that the number of required operations for the algorithm is around $M m³$.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is there a relation between this and the size of the matrix to be constructed? Like is $m$ the number of rows/columns of the matrix?

Comment: Yes for sure. Typically $m$ would be the size of the matrix.

Comment: is it completely the opposite concept for the order of error of the error term in a Taylor expansion? Because there the more the order, the better. But here it seems more is actually worse.